# Finding the union and intersecton of a indexed family of intervals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $V_i=\left[1+\dfrac{1}{i},7-\dfrac{1}{i}\right]$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

My attempt:

It is quite obvious to see that the two intervals will be $[1,2)$ and $(6,7]$ so I would think that the union of the two would be $[1,2) \cup (6,7]$ and the intersection would be $\emptyset$ but I get the feeling this doesn't look correct. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't $[2,6]$, is it?

Comment: they get like $[1,7]$ but I dont know how they arrive at that answer. I need to see a systematic way of doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersection: $[2,6]$

Union: $(1,7)$

To see each of these, notice that $x$ is in the intersection of the $V_i$ if and only if, it is in each $V_i$. Also note that $V_i \subset V_{i+1}$ as $1/i > 1/(i+1)$ and so $1+1/i> 1+ 1/(i+1)$ and $7 - 1/i > 7 - 1/(i+1)$. Hence
$$ V_i = [1 + 1/i,7 - 1/i] \subset [1 + 1/(i+1),7 - 1/(i+1)] = V_{i+1}$$

Therefore, $x$ is in the intersection if and only if $x$ is in $V_1 = [2,6]$.

For the union, note that $x$ is in the union if and only if $x$ is in at least one of the $V_i$. Let $x\in (1,7)$ then there is some $n$ such that $x-1/n >1$ and $x+ 1/n <7$ and so $x\in V_n$ hence the union contains $(1,7)$. Let $x$ be in the union, then $x$ is in one of the $V_i$. As each $V_i \subset (1,7)$ we have that $x\in (1,7)$ and so the union is $(1,7)$.

Comment: isn't $V_{i+1} \subset V_{i}$

Comment: @adam No, $V_1 = [1+1,7 - 1]=[2,6]$, $V_2= [1+1/2,7-1/2] = [1.5,6.5]$

Answer (score 1):

$V_i \subset V_{i+1}$ To see that this is true let $V_i = [a_i, b_i]$ then $a_{i+1} \lt a_i$ and $b_{i+1} \gt b_i$

So the intersection is the smallest in the family, which is $V_1 = [2, 6]$. The the union of the first n intervals is the last one , $V_n$, and as $n \rightarrow \infty$ $a_i \rightarrow 1$ and $b_i \rightarrow 7$, so the union is (1, 7)

The union is the open interval because you can find a member of the family that contains any point arbitrarily close to 1+ or 7-, but no interval that actually contains 1 or 7.

(also amended intersection: second answer is correct on this, mine was an arithmetical error).

Comment: open interval in the union...

Comment: @james, yes I think you are right.